# Angular 4 - To validate the pattern tag for the same input field in two conditions

Tags: angular

I need to validate a input field price.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="ui-grid-row">
    <div class="ui-grid-col-2"><label for="contact">Contact:</label></div>
    <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
        <select id="contact" name="contact" [(ngModel)]="register.contact" #contact="ngModel" class="form-control">
            <option *ngFor="let contact of contactAll" [value]="contact">{{contact}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-col-2"><label for="price">Price:</label></div>
    <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
        <input type="text" id="price" name="price" [(ngModel)]="register.price" #limit="ngModel" class="form-control" pattern="[0-9]+" required />
        <div *ngIf="price.invalid && (price.dirty || price.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="price.errors.required" class="errors">
                Price is required.
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="register.contact==='Housecontact' && !price.valid" class="errors">
                The price must be major than 0 if contact is "Housecontact".
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="register.contact==='Officecontact' && !price.valid" class="errors">
                The price must be greater than or equal to 0 if the contact is "Officecontact".
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm validating the price field, if field "Contact" field contains the value "Housecontact" and the value entered in the input field is greater than 0, es correcto and if the field "Contact" contents the value "Officecontact" and the value entered is greater or equal than 0 also is correct, the problem is, How I can to change the pattern tag of price field, in the first case would be pattern="0*[1-9][0-9]*(.[0-9]+)?" and the second case would be pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*$"

How could do it? thanks,

Comment: Try using == instead of ===

Comment: do you get any error messages in console?

Comment: I tested with '==' and with '===' and nothing, do not show anything in the console, the error layer is displayed but it does not show the error message

Comment: It seems like a reference issue to me:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators

Comment: also, I generally use methods to compare objects, instead of putting it straight into html, this will keep your code clean and allows for easy debugging :
compareString(a: string, b: string) {}...

Comment: Sorry, I have to reformulate the question, because if it works, but I need to solve an aspect related to the same but I have your recommendation very much in mind

Comment: I think if I put the pattern(regex) in a class variable, it will works fine, thanks to all